# Force list type in $min update operator

Tags: mongodb

I have documents with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "mins" : {
        "ts1" : {
            "node1" : [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ],
            "node2" : [
                4,
                5,
                6
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to update documents by taking the component-wise minimum for an array. As MongoDB does not support $min on arrays (I think), I'm updating each index individually like so:

```
db.foo.updateOne(
    {"_id" : 0},
    {$min: {
        "mins.ts3.node1.0": 1,
        "mins.ts3.node1.1": 2
    }}
)
```

This works fine but the problem is that if the document does not have the array before updating, MongoDB creates a nested document instead of an array:

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "mins" : {
        "ts1" : {
            "node1" : [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ],
            "node2" : [
                4,
                5,
                6
            ]
        },
        "ts3" : {
            "node1" : {
                "0" : 1,
                "1" : 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to tell MongoDB it is updating a list even if the list does not exist yet?**

I'd like to avoid creating empty lists for each document as that would break my current program design.

Comment: Please don't use `...`  as data in your documents, It's useful to post sample documents that people can work with, alongside the expected output. Also FYI MongoDB does support `$min` on array. It really  depends on what you are trying to  do.

Comment: Ah sorry I did not think of that. I'll edit. And yes $min on array works but only on the whole array, not component-wise.